# Getting NA when using as.Date()

Tags: r, datetime

Thanks to comments below, I realized I should use `"%b"` for `"FEB"` (originally I used `"%m"`; thanks for the reference to `?strptime`). But my problem still stands.

When I do

```
as.Date("13-FEB-15", "%d-%b-%y")
# [1] NA
```

I know this will work:

```
as.Date("13-02-2015", "%d-%m-%Y")
# [1] "2015-02-13"
```

But is there a way to avoid converting `FEB` to `02` and `15` to `2015` in order to get my expected result? Thanks!

Comment: `as.Date(as.character("13-FEB-15"), format = "%d-%b-%y")`. 
See `?strptime` for formats

Comment: Oli, check the `format` argument Sumedh shows. I find this site a great resource for working with strptime/strftime: http://strftime.org.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**A general and useful diagnostic**

Try this and what do you get?

```
format(strptime(Sys.Date(), format="%Y-%m-%d"), "%y-%b-%d")
```

I got

```
[1] "16- 7月-22"
```

Haha, the middle one is Chinese. So what is going wrong? Nothing wrong. The issue is that `%b` is sensitive to your current locale. When you read `?strptime`, pay special attention to what format is sensitive to your current locale.

My locale is:

```
Sys.getlocale("LC_TIME")
#[1] "zh_CN.UTF-8"
```

Yep, that is in China region.

Locales make a difference in Date-Time format. On my machine:

```
as.Date("16-JUL-22", "%y-%b-%d")
# NA
as.Date("16- 7月-22", "%y-%b-%d")
#[1] "2016-07-22"
```

Now let's reset time locale:

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "C")
as.Date("16-JUL-22", "%y-%b-%d")
#[1] "2016-07-22"
```

Wow, it works! Read `?locales` for more, and you will understand what `locale = "C"` means.

---

**Solution for you**

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "C")
as.Date("13-FEB-15", format = "%d-%b-%y")
```

Answer (score 2):

Using lubridate:

```
library(lubridate)
date1 = "2014-12-11 00:00:00"
date2 = "14-DEC-11"
ymd_hms(date1) == ymd(date2,tz = "UTC")
```

These equal each other and should be able to be joined.